# Is there a System.Text.Json's substitute for Json.NET's JsonProperty(Order)?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

Since `System.Text.Json` is now *the* JSON lib for [.NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.0), is there an attribute/param matching Json.NET's [`JsonProperty(Order)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm)? I browsed through the classes extending [`System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonAttribute.cs), but none seem to serve this purpose.

Going through `JsonSerializer.Write.HandleObject.cs` etc. didn't show me anything that could directly replace the legacy attribute here. Did I miss something, and, if not, what is the simplest way to replicate the legacy behaviour here?